# Android make a dialogbox  from an non ui-activity class 

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-activity

I don't need the code for the creation Dialog box on an activity.
I use opengles and i am drawing with the renderer class i create . I think the execution at the android activity window stays at main activity. 
I have states of my drawing and when a draw reach a state i want to post a dialog box. So there is a problem with that because the dialogbox builder wants a context and the renderer class isnt an activity object. 
I am new at opengles and firstly all the work i do exists at
method

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
{ }
```

so i have 2 classes 1st the ui class

```
mainactivity extends activity
```

and second the renderer class

```
class mainrenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer
```

i want from the second class to use activity operations such as create dialog box .
Can you give me a solution to this ?
Thanks.

In other words i want from a class (renderer) that isn't ui class to make a dialogbox .

**edited**

i pass the context of my activity class
as `myrender = new Renderer1(this);`
 at constructor of Renderer i have

```
class Renderer1 implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer
/* initializations */

public Renderer(Context context) {
 super();
 mcontext = context; 
}
```

and after that i have implement the `on drawFrame` method and when i reach a state i call the method `alertdialogbox()`
given below

```
 public void alertdialogbox()  /* some code */  AlertDialog.Builder
 builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext);
```

but it keeps erroring and application crashes when reach the state that the alertdialogbox called

the error begins with

> java.lang.RuntimeException : Can't create handler inside thread that
>   has not called Looper.prepare()

**Edit 2 solved**
i initialize a handler at main activity as :

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {
          @Override
          public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
              alertdialogbox();
             }
         };
```

alertdialogbox is a method that i declare inside main activity class
and constructs the dialogbox

again inside the main activity where i instantiate the GlsurfaceView and the Glrenderer
i pass the handler that i initialize before so :

```
    Renderer = new Renderer1(handler);  
after that at the class Renderer1

    class Renderer1 implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer
     Handler mhandler;

    public Renderer( Handler handler) {
     super();
     mhandler = handler; 
    }

    *
    *
public void onDrawFrame(){
*
*

if (state) 
{ 
alertdialogbox();
 }
}
*
*
     public void alertdialogbox()
        {

            mhandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);

        }
```

and  finally i have my dialogbox viewed.

thanks for the suggetions .

Comment: You could create a method makeDialog which takes a `context` as parameter or when creating `MainRenderer` pass along a context to have it as a class field. It's hard to write a more specific answer without knowing in which way you intent to use the code :)

Comment: It's easier to read if you edit your question and write the code in there. Also for crashes it's good to provide the error and it's stack trace 'cause that's where all the information is :o)

Comment: Your renderer class is not executing on the UI thread, hence the error.  I suggest you have a look at `Handler` class.  Create a handler in your main activity and pass it to the renderer on creation.  Then use this handler to create the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a `AlertDialog` (or any other UI widget) from another class, you must have a reference to your activity class and with that object, you can call `activity.runOnUIThread()` to execute any code related to your AlertDialog.